# Is there a better way to find the field of an object with a value of this object?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a better way to do the following:

```
obj = {
    "1111": {"name": "Peter", "descr": "....."},
    "2222": {"name": "Alex", "descr": "....."},
    "3333": {"name": "Tom", "descr": "....."}
};

function getUserIdBy(field, value, object) {
    var res;
    Object.keys(object).forEach(id => {
        if (object[id][field] === value) res = id;
    })
    return res;
}

console.log(getUserIdBy('name', 'Tom')); // return a string : "3333"
```

Comment: It would only be better if you would declare your variable and stopped using `var`

Comment: Maybe don't use an object at all? You could use an array of objects, and have the key as an id in each object - then use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Comment: Yeah, adding to what @Andy said basically, I think it'd make it a far more useful question if you specified in no uncertain terms what you _have_ and _must have_ -- e.g. format of data that comes your way which you'd rather not or cannot change --, and where you can accept alternative solutions. Because the "find a particular user in a dataset" problem has been solved, efficiently, a million times already, with nearly as many different approaches. Without specifics, this question is vague enough to be nearly useless, unfortunately, more so to anyone stumbling on it later on here.

Comment: `Object.entries(object).find(([, o]) => o[field] === value)?.[0]` should do it. But in most cases it would be better if your objects would also contain their own ID, then this would also simplify to `Object.values(object).find(o => o[field] === value)?.id`

Comment: Why aren't you passing the awaited third parameter to your function?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, I found that :

```
function getCharacterIdBy(field, value, object) {
    return Object.keys(object).filter(id => object[id][field] === value)
}
```

And I will look to change my object to an array.

Comment: I realised that I could return an array. My bad...

Answer (score 0):

You can use also this solution:

```
function getUserIdBy(field, value, object) {
  for (var id in object) {
    if (object[id][field] === value) {
      return id;
    }
  }
}

getUserIdBy('name', 'Peter', obj); // 1111
getUserIdBy('name', 'Tom', obj); // 3333
getUserIdBy('name', 'Alex', obj); // 2222
getUserIdBy('name', 'Bob', obj); // undefined
```